# Persisting Dockerized Consul KV Store across container runs

Tags: docker, consul, docker-volume

Mac OS here running Docker Desktop. I am trying to get the official [Consul Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul) to persist its KV store across runs. I am running that image with the following command:

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 -v /Users/myuser/tmp/consul:/consul/data -d --name=dev-consul -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul
```

After I enter that command, I am able to store a KV pair there:

```
curl --request PUT --data "3" http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/456
```

And then I can fetch it to make sure its there:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/456
true
```

But once I stop the container:

```
docker stop <containerId>
```

And then restart it:

```
docker restart <containerId>
```

And the try to fetch it again (using same curl to GET as above), **its gone!** I would think that the `-v /Users/myuser/tmp/consul:/consul/data` that I specify on the `docker run` command would prompt Consul to persist the KV store to that local directory on my machine, no?

It definitely persisted *something* there, though:

```
ls -al ~/tmp/consul/
-rw-------   1 myuser  staff    36 Mar 28 20:35 node-id
drwx------   3 myuser  staff    96 Mar 28 20:35 proxy
```

What do I need to do so that the KV store persists across multiple 
container runs?

Comment: From https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/: "Running the Consul container with no arguments will give you a Consul server in development mode."

Comment: Yes @DavidMaze, I *do* want a Consul *server* (not client). Curious about your development mode comment though...does Development Mode prompt Consul *not* to persist KV data? And if so, any idea what arguments I *do* need to supply to get it to do so?

Comment: There's a ton of information on the image page I linked above.

Comment: Thanks again @DavidMaze (+1 again), can you just confirm that what I want is to run the container w/ Consul in **Server Mode**? Again, just looking for a *single* instance of Consul server running, not server cluster/quorum, etc. Stupid simple.

Answer (score 3):

Running Consul agent (both server and client mode) in development mode does not persist any state. From [getting started guide](https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/getting-started/agent#starting-the-agent)

> This mode is useful for bringing up a single-node Consul environment quickly and easily. It is not intended to be used in production as it does not persist any state.

Running Consul agent without `-server` flag will get you a client as you can see during agent start in the output:

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Consul agent running!
      Version: 'v1.4.1'
      Node ID: '<uuid>'
      Node Name: 'node-name'
      Datacenter: 'dc1'
      Server: false (Bootstrap: false)
```

So for single instance server you would need a command like this (please note `-bootstrap` option which will make Consul automatically elect it self as cluster leader, so you will have operational single server "cluster")

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 -v /Users/myuser/tmp/consul:/consul/data -d --name=dev-consul -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul  agent -server  -data-dir=/consul/data -bootstrap
```

And now you should see  in `~/tmp/consul/` following files and directories:

```
checkpoint-signature  node-id  proxy  raft  serf
```

If you try putting data into KV store and reboot container with same volume as `data-dir` you should have your previously stored data there.

Comment: Thanks @bagljas (+1) however your `docker run...` command isn't working for me. When I run it, the container starts but when I go to `https://localhost:8500` in my browser nothing comes up.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup if you need graphical UI for Consul you will need to pass `-ui` argument to Consul agent command i.e. `docker run -p 8500:8500 -v /Users/myuser/tmp/consul:/consul/data -d --name=dev-consul -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul  agent -server  -data-dir=/consul/data -bootstrap -ui` If you were able to access UI from your browser earlier, then this should work as well. I know there might be some additional setup needed for Docker to expose container ports on `localhost` of the host machine. But I'm not running Mac OS myself.